# Sql Inner Join first record only if Exists Take Next one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

This one is support hard for me. I can do inner join with first result only, but if exist I want take 2nd result.

THIS IS MY TABLE A

```
ID NAME VALUE
1   A     123
2   B     456
3   C     789
4   A     456
```

TABLE B

```
BID BNAME BVALUE
1    A     ABC
2    A     CDE
3    B     845
4    C     1234
```

MY SELECT SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM A
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
        FROM B

    WHERE A.Name = B.BName 

) BB
```

It return

```
1   A     123  1   A   ABC
2   B     456  3   B   845
3   C     789  4   C   1234
4   A     456  1   A   ABC
```

Please help, I want this result:

```
1   A     123  1   A   ABC
2   B     456  3   B   845
3   C     789  4   C   1234
4   A     456  2   A   CDE
```

I accept tmp table and any kind of query :(

Comment: Both table A and table B have `A X 2,B X 1,C X 1`. What would the desired results look like if they didn't have the same number for one of the names?

Comment: Just think it is always same number of rows.

Comment: So you want to get `(1, 1)` and `(4, 2)`, and not: `(1, 2)` and `(4, 1)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following clarification in the comments that both tables will always have matching rows.

```
WITH A
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY ID) AS RN
         FROM   TableA),
     B
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BNAME ORDER BY BID) AS RN
         FROM   TableB)
SELECT A.ID,
       A.NAME,
       A.VALUE,
       B.BID,
       B.BNAME,
       B.BVALUE
FROM   A
       JOIN B
         ON A.NAME = B.BNAME
            AND A.RN = B.RN
```